# What is the difference between 兄 and 兄上?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between 兄 and 兄上?
These two words both mean ‘older brother’, but is there any nuance in the meaning?

Comment: This will help your question!! https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30053/38911 By the way, I save my family's numbers on my smartphone as 母上, 父上, 姉上. This is not normal even for Japanese, but when my friend see my phone coming call from them, he/she get laugh!! Because he/she found my greatest respect to my mother, father and sister.

Comment: Thank you very much)