# Particle used after referring to family members

Tags: grammar, particles

In watching Taiga dramas, I often hear people say

Haha ve (mother)
Chichi ve (father)
Ani ve (older brother)

You get the idea.

That's what it sounds like to me anyway.  But I'm not really sure which particle is really being used.  I don't seem to see it in my basic Japanese lessons.

Can anyone please clarify what they are doing for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Japanese doesn't have a "v" sound in native words. Are you referring to words like 母上 (ははうえ), 父上 (ちちうえ), etc? 上 is not a particle here, just a part of a compound for a more polite version of the various words.

Comment: 上 (うえ) is not a particle but an honorific suffix. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30004/5010